# Keystore - lost alias but have password and file

Tags: keystore

I lost my keystore alias but I have the keystore file and all the passwords. Is there any way I can find out what my keystore alias is?

I have been trying to use cmd to show the info inside keystore but without succes. Can someone thoroughly tell how to retrieve my alias? :)

Answer (score 5):

If you're talking about the keystore for the Play Store, you can do this:

`keytool -list -keystore your_keystore_file.keystore`

You should see the alias name before the date of its creation!

Something like that: http://vancelucas.com/blog/listing-aliases-inside-an-android-keystore-file-with-keytool/

But please, don't ever lose you password! I did it once and needed to create another AppID for my application.

Hope it helps you :)

Comment: Yeah that is what I ment. I wonder though what the last part of cmd "com.example.keystore" is? The name of my keystore file is jakttider key.jks.keystore and is located within C:\Users\Oscar\Desktop\Appar och filer. How should I type this into cmd?

Comment: go to the file's current directory using cmd, and just use the command :)

Usually, names like "com.example.keystore" are the application's id, so, what you have to type is the file's name (jakttider key.jks.keystore). After that, you will be asked to type your password for this keystore.

Comment: Maybe the problem is your path. I'm not using Windows right now, but I think you should add '\' before the white spaces in your path. Try using "tab" to autocomplete the path when you're typing the command!

Comment: Hi @user4071083,

Have you solved the problem? If yes, please set my answer as the correct one! ^^

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I downloaded a program and was able to see the alias of the keystore file. However it did not display my two passwords (thank god I wrote them down). So if anyone have the same problem as me I recommend them to download a program which will open the keystore file and display it's name/alias. Although I was not able to figure out a solution with your solution (most likely because I'm new to programming) I'm grateful that you tried to help me out!